# Resource Scopes not showing on Consent Page

Tags: identityserver4

I posed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913342/do-i-still-need-decryptionkey-and-validationkeykeys-in-aspnet-core-with-sep) earlier mentioning my difficulty in reaching my resource server. It just occurred to me that my consent page does not show the "Application Access" portion. It shows only the " Personal Information" portion.
When I check the scopes table I see all the scopes available in there but some how the resource scopes are not showing on the consent page

[image]
I am inclined to believe that this is most likely the cause of my woes.

I am using the following for my development
VS 2015 update 3
IdentityServer 4 rc 2
Angular2

My resource server and authentication server are in separate projects

and I am also following this [tutorial](https://damienbod.com/2016/03/02/angular2-openid-connect-implicit-flow-with-identityserver4/) and this sample [codes](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet6IdentityServer4AngularOidcFlows)
[image]

How do I get the "Application Access" Portion to show up?

Answer (score 1):

I believe consent pages are only for identity scopes not resource scopes. They are there to ask the user to confirm consent to weather or not the application can have access to portions of the users identity as defined by the identity scopes. Resource scopes are application level and are granted or not based on weather or not the application (client) is configured to be allowed access to that resource scope.

Comment: Thanks for the response. if this is the case, why is the index page holding codes that seeks to display similar content on consent page for application access

Comment: Oh I see I stand corrected. is your application requesting those scopes in its request?

Comment: You might want to break things down a little bit for me. Just started getting used to things in this environment.

Comment: What does the scopes parameter in your query string say when you are on the login/consent Screen?

Comment: scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520email%2520%2520roles%26nonce%3DN0.440259249600560841480679688563%26state%3D14806796885630.14274209986301312

Comment: I can see my "resource_server" the resource scope name is not in there. I guess I should put it in there. Right

Comment: Yeah, right got it working. Thanks a million. But I still have this error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '", If I remove the [Authorize] attribute I get access to the controllers in the resource server. If I put it back I get the above error. Hope you can step me through this one too

Comment: Have you added the ASPNET Core CORS middle ware?